# Making a Resource Handle Accessible in the Controller

Tags: parameter-passing, oat++

I have a resource (like a DB connection) which I need to instantiate when Oat++ initially loads. I do this in App.cpp in the main function. The resource can provide me with one or more handles which I generate in main.  I would like to have one of these handles available globally in MyController as it is needed for several endpoints.

My problem is that I don't know how to pass the handle(s).  The function run() in main passes no variables and even if I modified it, I'm not sure what I'd do next.

/* Create MyController and add all of its endpoints to router */
router->addController(std::make_shared());

Perhaps when I add the controller?

This is more of a C++ framework question as opposed to Oat++ (which is running nicely save this needed improvement)

I've looked around for similar situations like opening a DB at startup and generating multiple connectors, but I haven't found anything.

Comment: Resolved:  Oatpp has an App.cpp and in there you will find a main() as well as a run().  If the handle is created in main(), you modify run() to accept a single argument (hndl).  In run() pass that argument in to the controller instantiation like so:  
  router->addController(std::make_shared<MyController>(hndl)); In MyController.hpp, modify the prototype to be aware of this new variable.  MyController(void *hndl, OATPP_COMPONENT(std::shared_ptr<ObjectMapper>, objectMapper))
    : oatpp::web::server::api::ApiController(objectMapper), myhandle (hndl)  Declare myhandle private: section..